# Android tools r17 x86 emulator - why can't I create an x86 AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've installed the new tools without problems. I've installed the Intel HAXM. I've verified (with `sc query intelhaxm`) that the Intel service is running. I've also confirmed the machine (a Lenovo ThinkCentre) supports Intel Virtualization Technology.

So why in the AVD Manager is the CPU/ABI field fixed at ARM for every single platform version of Android?

Comment: Did you download the "Intel Atom x86 System Image" for Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10)?

Comment: Aha, that was it. Thanks Mark.

Comment: Feel free to add an Answer, and I'll vote up and mark as correct

Answer (score 24, accepted):

At the time of this writing, the only available x86 emulator image is for Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10), listed in the SDK Manager as "Intel Atom x86 System Image". Hopefully others will become available in the future.

BTW, for those reading this question and answer and going "huh?", the r17 edition of the Android developer tools [added support for native x86 emulators](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm), which will run somewhat faster than their ARM emulator equivalents.

Comment: I knew they'd added this feature, I read the instructions twice, and *still* I couldn't work out what I needed to do. Thanks for pointing out the lacking necessary detail.

Comment: Sometimes I'm baffled why some of this stuff isn't documented. It mentions the "Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager", but not the "Intel Atom x86 System Image". Next Google will do something crazy, like have Google I/O be a random lottery system instead of a first-come first-served.

Anyway, thanks as always Mark :)

Comment: Also keep in mind that under the Android Virtual Device Manager, you'll need to choose the "Intel Atom x86 System Image (Intel Corporation) - API Level 10" Target (not the generic Android 2.3.3 - API Level 10 Target).

Comment: Intel has [step-by-step instructions](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-the-intel-atom-tm-android-x86-emulator-image-add-on-from-the-android-sdk-manager/) that make clear the need to step down to API Level 10 (ugh!)

Comment: Now it's also available for Nougat (API Level 25)

Answer (score 2):

You can download Android emulator images direct from [Intel's website](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/).  [Here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/android-44-kitkat-x86-emulator-system-image) they have a KitKat image that looks to be API 19 (4.4).

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep this question up to date:

Like [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) said, at the time of that writing, the only Intel x86 images available were API 10. Some time ago **Intel started updating images in sync with SDK releases**.

In order to use the images, you may download them from the SDK Manager, or follow [Intel's Instructions](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-jelly-bean-43-installation-instructions-manually) (4.3-specific, but apply generally).

Despite what you use, note an important point of the instructions:

- **select non-"Google APIs" targets** (e.g. "Android 4.3 - API Level 18") - the AVD Manager won't let you change CPU to x86 unless using vanilla droid targets.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you'll need a "Target" called "Google APIs x86 (Google Inc.) - API Level 19. Or such. Otherwise, the CPU/ABI choice does not list "Intel Atom (x86)". Slight difference in behavior of what is listed and what choices either due to launch from command line versus ADT or due to other choices made on that screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had a startup issue on ubuntu as well. To get it working I used the `-disable-kvm` option. Took three days to find this solution.

```
./emulator -avd i -noaudio -nojni -netfast -show-kernel -verbose -gpu on -cpu-delay 0 -qemu -m 512 -disable-kvm
```